# Access: Adding a Report Total to a Query?

Tags: ms-access, parameters, report, field, controls

I have a field on my report underneath an employee name footer that totals up an employees average number of units processed an hour.  I call it AVG UPH.  I need to use that total as a control on the query that the report is based on.  Is this possible?  Every time I try to add that to my query, the query fails to run and asks me what that field is with the little popup box where you're supposed to type something.

Here is the field name from the report:

AccessTotalsPieceSorterRawData.AVG UPH

and

Here is the Query Column Field I am trying to call:

AvgUPHPS: [Reports]![PieceSorterHomeAverages]![AccessTotalsPieceSorterRawData]![AVG UPH]

When I try to run the Query, it pops up a box and asks me to "Enter the Parameter Value" for Reports!PieceSorterHomeAverages!AccessTotalsPieceSorterRawData!AVG UPH

I'm stumped.  Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating something like a circle reference here, that won't work.

Before the report can calculate and show the `AVG UPH` field, it needs to read the data from its source query. So the query cannot reference that field. A different query can, once the report is open in Report view or Page preview.

Also, your 4-part expression sounds like `AccessTotalsPieceSorterRawData` is a subreport? Then it should probably be

```
[Reports]![PieceSorterHomeAverages]![AccessTotalsPieceSorterRawData].Report![AVG UPH]
```

(compare http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm : `Forms!Mainform!Subform1.Form!ControlName` )

Comment: I don't believe it's a subreport.  I simply clicked on one of my report fields (right clicked) and selected "Totals: Average".  That placed the average down in the Employee Name Footer b/c I group everything by employee name.

I was afraid it was a circular reference.  I just hoped that Access was smart enough to run a dummy report, gather the totals, then apply that to the information.  I guess not haha!

Comment: Your report's name must be `PieceSorterHomeAverages` or `AccessTotalsPieceSorterRawData`, it can't be both. So the latter must be some sort of sub-object in the report.

Comment: What I posted is how Access Autogenerates it by selecting it from their menu's in the builder???

Now I am trying to use my report named: PieceSorterHome that also finds the averages but doesn't exclude anyone as the base report.  Then use the a new Query to look at the text box value AccessTotalsPieceSorterRawData.AVG UPH from that PieceSorterHome Report.  However, even with that report open and the averages displayed, the query still asks me to Enter the Parameter Value for: Reports!PieceSorterHome!AccessTotalsPieceSorterRawData!AVG UPH

Comment: Also, would something in the Footer for the Employee Name grouping be a subreport text box then?  I didn't specifically insert a subreport, but if Access did that automatically and just calls it "Employee Name Footer", then what you were originally saying would make a ton of sense.  I am by no means a guru in Access.